# Is there a difference between a letter and a letter with combining marks?

Tags: keyboard-layout, unicode

I found the International English layout on XKB hard to use, so I wrote my own with all the French accents as combining diacritic marks on AltGr.

So is there a difference between combined letters, like "è" (U+00E8) and "è" (U+0065 + U+0300)? Some text editors combine them to a one unit, while others see two different symbols for backspacing. Also the last looks weird on Firefox.

Comment: The general topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence

Comment: Two characters are not the same as one. The rest depends on the viewing software implementation.

Comment: @harrymc it is one character fir Unicode.

Comment: Please see the above link to understand the difference.